# Question concerning functors which are equivalences

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, functors

I am currently reading about monoidal categories in the book "Tensor categories" and I am confused about the following: The authors write that the functors $L_1: X \mapsto 1 \otimes X$ and $R_1: X \mapsto X \otimes 1$ are autoequivalences of $C$. My question is

> What does it mean that $R_1$ and $L_1$ are autoequivalences ?

Can someone give me some explanations ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you know what an equivalence of categories is?

Comment: Assuming you do know what an equivalence is, this just means that $L_1$ and $R_1$ are equivalences from $C$ to itself. This is immediate for any endofunctor equipped with an isomorphism to the identity functor.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I was just missing the definition of an equivalence of categories. In fact, I studied monoidal categories without knowing this fundamental definition.